# Unable to set Cookie in php

Tags: php, html, cookies, setcookie

I am working with social login.  I tried [login with facebook](http://www.vignesh.gvignesh.org/oauthreg/reg.html).  Once the user is authenticated I can get their value and I need to set their id in a cookie so that I can create a session across the site.

Here is my code,

```
<?php
/*
 * login_with_facebook.php
 *
 * @(#) $Id: login_with_facebook.php,v 1.2 2012/10/05 09:22:40 mlemos Exp $
 *
 */
    require('http.php');
    require('oauth_client.php');

    $client = new oauth_client_class;
    $client->server = 'Facebook';
    $client->redirect_uri = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
        dirname(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?')).'/login_with_facebook.php';

    $client->client_id = ''; $application_line = __LINE__;
    $client->client_secret = '';

    if(strlen($client->client_id) == 0
    || strlen($client->client_secret) == 0)
        die('Please go to Facebook Apps page https://developers.facebook.com/apps , '.
            'create an application, and in the line '.$application_line.
            ' set the client_id to App ID/API Key and client_secret with App Secret');

    /* API permissions
     */
    $client->scope = 'email';
    if(($success = $client->Initialize()))
    {
        if(($success = $client->Process()))
        {
            if(strlen($client->access_token))
            {
                $success = $client->CallAPI(
                    'https://graph.facebook.com/me', 
                    'GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
            }
        }
        $success = $client->Finalize($success);
    }
    if($client->exit)
        exit;
    if($success)
    {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook OAuth client results</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo "This is id i got from facebook ".$user->id." I am unable to set this value in cookie.";

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user_id', 'pwd');
mysql_select_db("DB Name");     

$sql    =   "INSERT INTO oauth SET auth_id  = ".$user->id.",
                                   name     = '".$user->name."',
                                   email    = '".$user->email."',
                                   link     = '".$user->link."'";
mysql_query($sql);

if(isset($_COOKIE['auth_id']))
    unset($_COOKIE['auth_id']);

setcookie("auth_id", $user->id, time()+60*60*24, "/");
?>

<script>
//window.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>OAuth client error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>OAuth client error</h1>
<pre>Error: <?php echo HtmlSpecialChars($client->error); ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Just setting the cookie after updating my domain.  But this is not working for me.

Comment: are you make sure user id is set ?

Comment: that's probably your cookies will be available only after next page refresh.

Comment: how do you test for the cookie to be set?

Comment: aren't cookies disabled by browser?

Comment: just type chrome://settings/cookies in chrome.  Check for vignesh.gvignesh.org domain and you can see the cookie there

Comment: No if i use javascript function to set cookie its setting.  But i need to set from PHP.

Comment: @Charlie: After page refresh also cookie not available.

Comment: Please answer to Luceos question…

Comment: @feeela: My first answer is to Luceos.  Just checking my browser whether cookie set or not?

Comment: And did you check your browser after a page refresh or during your setcookie page request?

Comment: @All: You can probably check logging in.  I displayed your Userid at the end and written same code to set the cookie.  But its not updating.

Comment: Is this PHP code in-line, so is there HTML above the line where you set the cookie: `Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). ` As such, please post the complete php page.

Comment: @Luceos: Just see the code.  Updated for you.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the php.net website: `Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction).` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

You cannot set a cookie if you have already started output. Therefor you need to pull your setcookie code to above your first HTML.